# Statistical model for multi-subject multi-trial group comparisons

Tags: anova, t-test, repeated-measures, paired-data, bonferroni

I am quite a novice in statistics and I have a complex model (at least for me) that I need to build for a test. I have a treatment plan and I am doing some frequency measurements in different regions of the brain. The idea is to compare these measurements before and after treatment for the same group of subjects.

Essentially, I have:

- 5 subjects.
- 10 trials (5 before, 5 after treatment).
- In each of these trials I am measuring 3 frequency band powers (alpha,beta,gamma) in 3 different regions of the brain (so 9 measurements in total for each trial).

I guess averaging the trials and doing several paired t-tests for each of these 9 measurements with Bonferroni corrections wouldn't be the best way to do this. Should I try something like repeated measures ANOVA with some post-hoc tests? If so, what should my data table and formula look like?